# find correct azure web role ip address

Tags: azure, dns, ip, azure-web-roles

How can I find the static IP address for my Azure WebRole? I need to feel secure that I've gotten the right one, one which will remain static so long as I don't change the deployment (see following:
[Static IP address for Role in Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451423/static-ip-address-for-role-in-windows-azure),
[Produce Static IP address for hosting wcf service in web role on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698595/produce-static-ip-address-for-hosting-wcf-service-in-web-role-on-azure)).

I need the IP address because our Android app needs a domain range of IP addresses to work with for app notification purposes. (I.e. we're already using CNAME, so this has nothing to do with trying to go the A record route).

The problem is that I see a couple of conflicting possibilities:

1) I manually found the IP address for our running website with a typical online reverse domain name utility, namely this one worked: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/. The IP it gave was correct, I can paste it into the browser URL box and our site comes up. But I want to make sure this is the valid Macoy, because:

2) However, in Azure dash, if I select my web role, if I select "Manage Domains", curiously, it says the following: THE IP ADDRESS TO USE WHEN YOU CONFIGURE A RECORDS: NNN.NN.NN.NNN (real number is given), which DIFFERS from the one discovered above, even though interestingly the first 3 numbers (NNN) match, and the second number (NN) is only 1 digit different (e.g. 36 instead of 35).

Why would this be??? And also, that IP address does *not* work when I paste in the browser url box.

So while I could given the IP address from #1, I just feel insecure about why the only IP address I can find for our site in the Azure panel itself doesn't work and is different. I do not want the one this external website found to be somehow incidental or not the real one to use.

P.S. I also wouldn't mind learning what this talk of a "VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS" is in the dash:
"VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS: No IP Based SSL binding is configured".

EDIT: Thanks for the answer. To clarify a bit further: Go to ALL Items in the dash, find your Cloud Service and select that, and then on the right hand you will find the following:

```
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS (VIP)
123.23.45.678

INPUT ENDPOINTS
WidgetsInc.WebRole1:    123.23.45.678:80    
WidgetsInc.WebRole1:    123.23.45.678:443
WidgetsInc.WebRole1:    123.23.45.678:8172
WidgetsInc.WorkerRole1: 123.23.45.678:3389
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a web role, the IP address of the *cloud service* is in the dashboard as 'PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS (VIP)'. This is the only address that you can use and is the IP address of the load balancer for the service. IP addresses for individual instances are subject to change. Outgoing traffic will also appear to come from this public VIP - it is the only address to use.